# Upgrade to gradle 2.2.3 breaks my build

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-2.2

I'm trying to update my gradle file to work with version 2.2.3.
However, I get the following error when building:

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/LibraryPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

As far as I know, it's related to Java 8.
My code is targeting Java 7 as I can't update to Java 8 because the Jack compiler makes a lot of other problems I can't deal right now.

```
    compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

I guess what I should do is to target JAVA 7 but compile against JAVA 8.

[image]

And it seems that the path in the window above does direct to Java 8.

[image]

How I get over this??

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party dependencies that are compiled against Java 8?

Comment: No. It happens even if I create a new project with no other special dependencies

Comment: what give : `gradlew --version` (or `gradle --version`)

Comment: Gradle 2.14.1, JVM  1.7.0_79 (Oracle Corporation 24.79-b02)
  
Guess this is the problem - how can I make it work with JVM 1.8?
Even when I update my "sourceCompatibility" and "targetCompatibility" to 1.8 I still get this values and the above error.

Comment: Don't confuse the Java Gradle runs against with the source- and targetCompatibility of your sourcecode. If you run Gradle with Java 1.8 and say targetCompatibility 1.7, your code will still run on 1.7, but Gradle uses 1.8 to run. The error you get means that you use some class compiled for 1.8 in an 1.7 run. In your case you run Gradle with Java 1.7, but the Android plugin you use is compiled against Java 1.8.

Comment: My project is just a new one I've just created with Android Studio.
Do I need to change something in my environment to get over this?

Comment: you can try add java path settings to gradle. something like this:
org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-change-java-home-using-gradle-proeprties/5649/2